# What's is the difference between slicing and stacking in a time-series analysis?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, time-series

My adviser told me that there are two categories of time-series in remote sensing: slicing and stacking.

What is the difference between time-series stacking and slicing pertaining to landcover change in the field of remote sensing

Answer (score 1):

**Stacking in Remote Sensing**

There is a great explanation of image stacking in another answer on here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/191300/97475

**Landsat Time Series Stack (LTSS)**

Being one of the longest running mid-resolution data sets, Landsat is a great resource for land use and land cover studies. It is particularly useful for time series analysis and the LTSS refers to a stack of Landsat images over a temporal interval on the same satellite path/row.

Providing these images are of the highest quality (near zero cloud cover) and radiometrically calibrated with the greatest care, then they can be used in change detection studies. This not only highlights where change has occurred but also refers to the change itself (i.e. from woodland to soil if logging has occurred).

The stacking of the Landsat bands and derivatives is applied to each image in time and should maintain the same parameters throughout. The change detection is then most commonly applied to the stacked image and compared against one another.